# TinyMCE is not embed with angular 4 app

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, jhipster, tinymce-4

I'm trying to embed the tinyMCE editor in a angular4 app. But failed to load it, and got this error saying

> tinyMCE is not defined.

[image]

I am following the documentation of the tinyMCE with this url https://www.tinymce.com/docs/integrations/angular2/

This is my code view [image]

Am i missing any steps or doing something wrong, any advice would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: @GaëlMarziou, i edited the question statement, my project is created using jhipster build process and running and installing the project <tinyMCE> using npm instead of ng serve.

Comment: The README.md file is saying to add the vendor.ts, and vendor.css file in the app.module.ts file. and i am already adding it. still no success so far...

Comment: added the vendor.scss screen shot but couldn't find the vendor.ts

Comment: Well then something is wrong, look at the sample app https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app it's at src/main/webapp/app/vendor.ts Which version of JHipster do you use? Please don't use images for text files just copy/paste so that if someone wants to modify them they can.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare tinymce in your component,

```
declare var tinymce: any;
```

Comment: i have already declare it in the file if its visible in the above screen shot